# When form (in a repeater) is submitted, then perform an action?

Tags: velo

I've been using Velo for the last week or so and I'm getting to grips with it. However I've come across a stumbling block and I can't seem to find any solutions in the documentation.

I have a repeater here:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is: Once the form has been submitted (it takes a while as there is a file upload), I want to be able to perform some actions like so...

```
$w.onFORMSUBMITTED?? {
        console.log('form is submitted, do stuff');
});
```

Is there a way to listen to the form submission success? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks for listening

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how you created the form. You probably want to use [`onWixFormSubmit()`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-crm/$w-wixforms/onwixformsubmit).

Answer (score 0):

"What I'm trying to achieve is: Once the form has been submitted (it takes a while as there is a file upload), I want to be able to perform some actions like so..."

You can use multi step box where **1** state is your form input + next button[hidden]
after form submit success a text message[hide] will display success msg and next button enabled. By clicking next button[2nd state] your user go and can upload.
Hope this help.